# Multiple Spring MVC applications on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have two different apps installed. First - ROOT.war and second one - sky.war
The problem that sky's requests are handled by ROOT's...
Where should I dig to?

Thank you

Comment: Put them on different ports

Comment: @patilharshal16 do you have some example or link of manual?

Comment: double click on servers then you will get 3 ports type tomcat admin, HTTP, AJP
So just change port numbers

Comment: is the problem you want sky's requests handled by root, or that you don't ?

Comment: No, both of them configured to listen /** folder, and I need that everyone listen his own root..

Answer (score 0):

If you want one request dispatcher ... You will need to set the tomcat startup option `crossContext` to true, this will allow you to return a request dispatcher for other web applications using `ServletContext.getContext()`.

Comment: And do I need to make additional configuration step except of crossContext = true?

Comment: @nKognito don't think so, but I have never done this. I would normally have one war fle, and multple different contexts within that. Otherwise I would rely on the the url mapping of war file to call a different request mapping. A third way is I think to use ears.

Comment: http://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/

Answer (score 0):

A simple scenario is to use two Tomcat instances (Tomcat-7one, Tomcat-7two).
Edit the server.xml file from `tomcat/config` folder the following way:
For the first instance:
     `<Connector  port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"` 
For the second instance:
     `<Connector  port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"`

Put one war in the webapp folder of the 1st tomcat instance 
and the second war - in the webapp folder of the second tomcat instance.
start both tomcats. 
your apps should be available at:
 `localhost:8080/ROOT/`  and `localhost:8081/sky/` prefixed by `http://`

Comment: this doesn't help the OP, this is simply setting up two tomcats or different ports

Comment: ohh I didn't get the question then

Comment: @NimChimpsky Yes, but if I'll install additional subdomain and redirect all requests to second instance it might help

Comment: @nKognito That's what i was answered but someone down voted my answer